# Xcode 8 importing StoreKit.framework cause error while archiving

Tags: ios, xcode, in-app-purchase, ios10, xcode8

in my app I imported `Tune.framework` for monitoring install, updates and other custom event. Now I have upgraded from Xcode7 to Xcode8 and I need to import `StoreKit.framework` which causes the enablement of `In-app purchase` capabilities.

So far, so good... the problem came when I try to archive the app with my In-house provisioning (i.e. an enterprise distribution) and I receive the error **Provisioning profile "xxx-InHouse" doesn't support the In-App Purchase capability.
Code signing is required for product type 'Application' in SDK 'iOS 10.0'**.

This provisioning is a wild card app Id, so I can enable the In-app purchase on app Id and I'm stuck.

Ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Switch off the in-app purchases switch on the capabilities tab